# How to add local images to facebook feed dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

As per my understanding FB feed dialog accepting url links of images how can i send or share image from a local file or Img object in feed dialog

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`Feed Dialog` needs the `picture` parameter to be a url only. So, you have to upload it to some server and give it the url.

OR,

You can use the [Photo API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) to post the photo to an album instead. You can use upload the local image with this using the image data. In fact, this is more useful to your case

Answer (score -1):

Facebook reads meta data from the page you want to share and takes that info to build the share / feed dialog:

On your page you want to share you need to add in the header:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="SECURE IMAGE URL (HTTPS)" />
```

You can debug your website you want to share here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: this answer is not relavant to the OP